# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined on localhost - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to add a class in a div but that is not working.

PHP - JS

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    if (is_page ('50')) { 
      ?>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            // your javscript code goes here
            window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
            console.log("HELLO");
            document.getElementById("all-categories").classList.add("mystyle");
            });
          </script>
      <?php
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown-categories collapse " id="all-categories">
```

DEVTOOLS

[image]

Comment: Is this the _exact_ code that is causing this error? Including the `document.getElementById("all-categories")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried splitting this line

```
document.getElementById("all-categories").classList.add("mystyle");
```

Into two lines to confirm the element exists, it's only one element, and has classList property?

```
var categories = document.getElementById("all-categories");
console.log(categories);
console.log(categories.classList); // I suspect this is undefined, thus .add() function doesn't exists
categories.classList.add("mystyle");
```

Comment: "_I suspect this is undefined_" That's what the error message says, but it doesn't really make sense. `document.getElementById()` returns either an `Element` object, or `null`. If it returns `null`, the error would've been "Cannot read property 'classList' of null". But if it returns an `Element`, `classList` shouldn't be `undefined`, as `classList` is a property of `Element`.

Comment: No need to be rude, I was just trying to help troubleshoot the problem. Like you said in your other comment I was leaving the chance to be outside the defined scope of the problem. I agree and could have worded it better. More information is required to further assess what the problem is. That's all I was saying and I was trying to not be accusatory since they could be new.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant rude. I'm just pointing out that, as far as I can see, OP's code should not be able to produce that error.

Comment: And while I agree with everything you said in your first comment (i.e. it should be Element or null so the error should be different), by technical definition it shouldn't happen and yet here we are with this error. We just need more information to determine what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @Melisa What was the result of these logs? Did this help you resolve the issue? If so, what was the problem?